# How to convert Cyrillic letters to English latin in Java String?

Tags: java, letters

I have string a=**"L1-23Миграција од VPN и промена на брзина ACTELIS Agregator alternativna 8-/208"**;

I would like for every my string to check if there are some Cyrillic letters in string and to convert them to English:

Output should look:

**L1-23Migracija od VPN i promena na brzina ACTELIS Agregator alternativna 8-/208**

Thanks!

Comment: Which encoding is the string in?

Comment: Did you do this for Bulgarian letters? It is similar I must do it for Macedonian letters

Comment: I have only implemented such thing with switch. I am almost sure there is no pre-written library as the transliteration can possibly be different for different languages. After all you only have to write 30 cases in a switch statement and you will have what you want.

Comment: 30 + 30 (small and upper letters yes?) OK I think it is acceptable. Can you please give me some code for that? Thanks!!!

Comment: And just one question- how do you different on example English "C" I suppose this is the S also in Bulgarian language? So how to tell it to if this is English C (like word "Case") do not convert and if it is Cyrillic C then to change it to S (on example Ситуација should be Situacija).

Comment: I don't have the code I have written - I did this for the last time about 10 years ago. It should be pretty straight-forward how to write it.

Comment: OK can you answer me on second question I think it might be big problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12150/discussion-between-izomorphius-and-dejan)

Comment: There is an **official transliteration on a per language basis**. For [Macedonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Macedonian)

Answer (score 2):

I found this method here on stackoverflow [Transliteration from Cyrillic to Latin ICU4j java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273318/transliteration-from-cyrillic-to-latin-icu4j-java), it is for converting cyrillic(Russian) to latin (but you can convert it the other way around if needed). I tweaked it a bit so it's compatible for Macedonian Cyrillic(I believe that's what you need). Here it is:

```
public static String convertCyrilic(String message){
    char[] abcCyr =   {' ','а','б','в','г','д','ѓ','е', 'ж','з','ѕ','и','ј','к','л','љ','м','н','њ','о','п','р','с','т', 'ќ','у', 'ф','х','ц','ч','џ','ш', 'А','Б','В','Г','Д','Ѓ','Е', 'Ж','З','Ѕ','И','Ј','К','Л','Љ','М','Н','Њ','О','П','Р','С','Т', 'Ќ', 'У','Ф', 'Х','Ц','Ч','Џ','Ш','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','/','-'};
    String[] abcLat = {" ","a","b","v","g","d","]","e","zh","z","y","i","j","k","l","q","m","n","w","o","p","r","s","t","'","u","f","h", "c",";", "x","{","A","B","V","G","D","}","E","Zh","Z","Y","I","J","K","L","Q","M","N","W","O","P","R","S","T","KJ","U","F","H", "C",":", "X","{", "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","/","-"};
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < abcCyr.length; x++ ) {
            if (message.charAt(i) == abcCyr[x]) {
                builder.append(abcLat[x]);
            }
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

And then just use

```
String converted = convertCyrillic(a);
```