# Transcription with Java

Tags: java

Does anyone know if there is any possibility about how can I for example transcribe Russian input to latin?

There is any framework that supports that? I was searching Charset but it doesn't support this case

Thx in Advance.

Comment: yes exactly;).. do have any idea??

Comment: You mean transliteration?

Comment: like this example  ж = zh  that mean transcription

Comment: This may be what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273318/transliteration-from-cyrillic-to-latin-icu4j-java

Comment: @adilos804 so you need phonetic transcription, as "молоко" -> "mala`ko"?

Comment: # christop it looks good do have any experience with this framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Map<Character, String> translit = new HashMap<>();
 static {
     translit.put('а', "a");
     translit.put('б', "b");
     translit.put('в', "v");
     // ...
     translit.put('ж', "zh");
     // and so on
 }


 public String transliterate(String input) {
     char[] c = input.toCharArray();
     StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
     for (char ch : c) {
         output.append(translit.contains(ch) ? translit.get(ch) : String.valueOf(ch));
     }
     return output.toString();
 }
```

Comment: #Sasha good idea but how can i outsource the character for example in properties datei?